# Imprimir la triangular superior e inferior de una matriz java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando imprimir la triangular superior e inferior de una matriz. En este caso elijo la

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

. El código es este:

```
public class matriztriangular {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
    int lado = matriz.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < lado; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);

        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int k = 0; k < lado; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l <= k; l++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[l][k]);

        }
     }
  }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al imprimir la triangular superior, me lo hace mal, en vez de salirme

> 1 2 3 5 6 9

me sale

> 1 2 5 3 6 9

(la triangular inferior si que me lo hace bien). ¿Alguien sabe donde esta el error en el código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema lo tienes el como estas recorriendo la matriz.

Prueba con esto

```
for (int i = 0; i < lado; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Su problema va sobre matrices cuadradas por lo tanto lo que dices no va a ocurrir.  Ademas no se porque dices que se imprime la matriz entera cuando eso NUNCA ocurre con este codigo.

Comment: si, en este ejemplo van a ser cuadradas pero considero mejor poner `j<matriz[i].length`. Lo otro no me di cuenta de la asignacion de `j=i` perdona

Comment: Si,     j<matriz[i].length queda mejor. Lo edito.

Comment: @Lithorell  Lo que estoy intentando es en el ejemplo ese de la matriz de la pregunta, imprima por una parte la triangular inferior, es decir 1 4 5 7 8 9 y por otra parte 9 6 5 3 2 1, es decir la triangular superior pero invertida. He cambiado cosas del código pero lo único que he logrado es que imprima 9 5 6 1 2 3.

Comment: Con el cambio que puse a mi me da 1 2 3 5 6 9

Comment: Si, eso esta bien pero luego me di cuenta que lo que necesito es coger de abajo a arriba para comparar ambas triangulares, es decir de la matriz principal, que imprima 9 6 5 3 2 1. He cambiado el código y ahora me imprime  9 5 6 1 2 3 y un error de ejecución.

Comment: Para imprimir 9 6 5 3 2 1 prueba con esto     
    for (int i = lado-1;i >=0; i--) {
        for (int j = matriz[i].length-1; j>=i; j--) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);

        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la ayuda de un contador:

```
int[][] matriz = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int cont = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++){
      for (int j=cont; j<matriz[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + ",");
      }
      cont++;
    }
```

La salida sería:

> 1,2,3,5,6,9,